# How do I resolve "connection string is not formatted correctly"?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create some Azure Functions. I started by working through the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs). The problem, I keep getting errors when I try to debug locally.

Here is my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XYZ;AccountKey=<removed>;BlobEndpoint=https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://XXX.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://XXX.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://XXX.file.core.windows.net/;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "QueueStorage": "https://XXX.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue-items"
  }
}
```

Here is the code (really just the templated code included for Azure Functions)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class SampleFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("SampleFunction")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "QueueStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output to the local console window:

```
[8/29/2017 5:53:01 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SampleFunction.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Failed to validate Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK QueueStorage connection string. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string is not formatted correctly. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841340 for details about configuring Microsoft Azure Storage connection strings.
[8/29/2017 5:53:01 PM] Error indexing method 'SampleFunction.Run'
[8/29/2017 5:53:01 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'SampleFunction.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Failed to validate Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK QueueStorage connection string. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string is not formatted correctly. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841340 for details about configuring Microsoft Azure Storage connection strings.
```

I tried rewriting the connecting string a few times but can't seem to get rid of the error. I reviewed the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string) but still can't get this to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing the slash after the end of each URL? Currently you have "core.windows.net/;" but you should have "core.windows.net;". Does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it expects a full Storage connection string there in settings instead of just the URL for the queue.

Something like:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XYZ;AccountKey=<removed>;BlobEndpoint=https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://XXX.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://XXX.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://XXX.file.core.windows.net/;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "QueueStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XYZ;AccountKey=<removed>;BlobEndpoint=https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://XXX.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://XXX.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://XXX.file.core.windows.net/;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As juunas said, we require the full connection string for `Connection` app settings.

If this connection is a duplicate of `AzureWebJobsStorage`, you can simply change your attribute to `[QueueTrigger("my-queue-items")]` (`AzureWebJobsStorage` is the default if no other connection is specified).